# Tooltip not showing for less date duration in step chart highcharts

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

> I am using highcharts for step chart.Tooltip is not showing for less
>   datetime duration.As you can see the code , I have add marker enabled
>   and message.Based on marker enabled toolip will get displayed.But the
>   tooltip contains marker enabled true and message forward-Two is not
>   displayed.Can you please help!!!

Please check this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/pze3qLg2/12/
`HighChart Step graph`

Comment: Solved this problem by using **findNearestPointBy** option.
 


`plotOptions: {
    line: {
      findNearestPointBy: 'xy',
    }
}`